How can we be certain that the nature of things is as we perceive them?
Can we we be certain that the nature of things is as we physically perceive them (and if so how); are our cognitive tools (senses, logic, language) sufficient to access absolute reality, or do they merely provide us with distorted images of the truth? It is common to understand there are illusions and distortions in vision or reason, but given the great philosophical disagreements about what is real and what is not, or the nature of reality itself, it seems that thinking about reality doesn't provide any unifying results that everyone can agree on.
According to modern philosophical theory, how can we be certain that the nature of things is as we perceive them?

Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism

Relevant: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/perception-problem/

Relevant: https://iep.utm.edu/perc-obj/

If our perceptions of reality (at least locally) weren't good approximations, we would have gone extinct ages ago.

@D.Halsey So you think the smell of cinnamon is something that exists in reality? Or the colour red? The problem of this evolutionary sort of thinking is that evolution selected us for fitness, not for our accurate perception of reality, only when it coincided.

Modern embodies cognition posits theory ladenness of perception so the nature of things perceived, if exists, is always relative...

Define "absolute reality".

@Philomath What do the smell of cinnamon or the colour red have to do with my comment?

@Philomath The point of my comment was precisely that evolutionary fitness is strongly enhanced by accurate perceptions of reality. Seems pretty obvious to me.

@D.Halsey Your smell of cinnamon doesn't exist in reality. Your color red doesn't exist in reality. They are useful mappings that enhance fitness. You will not find the smell of cinnamon anywhere,  only molecules that bind to a receptor... If you think molecules are the same as smell...

Added some detail in an attempt to prevent closure. Feel free to roll back.

We can never be certain that the nature of things is as we perceive them. The cognitive tools like senses, logic or language have limitations. Anybody can know it easily if they are analyzed. It has  already been known the different inborn abilities of other creatures which humans don't have. We cannot underestimate also the language animals use.

... do they merely provide us with distorted images of the truth?

Yes.  Different people or even same person at their different ages perceive things differently.  It can be verified from one's own experience.

To many modern philosophers, the idea there is an "absolute reality" is misguided thinking. In the 20th century, a number of findings and explanations have suggested that the notion there is a single, objective reality is a bad way to approach understanding physicalism. Notably, wave-particle duality suggests the idea that the act of observation itself determines how the physical universe behaves.
Naive realism at first convinces us a bit egotistically that what we see is what there is and what we should believe. If we see a red apple, we should believe the apple is red. But as the Ancient Greeks started realizing, there are a number of complications when we start thinking about things. Illusions, confabulations, hallucinations, deceptions, etc. This raises what is now called the problem of perception (SEP).
In the philosophy of science, some thinkers, notably Hanson, Sellars, McDowell, and Rorty have put forth various theses that undermine the idea that the correspondence theory of truth or our intuitions of reality through our perceptions are accurate and sufficient for explaining the universe. Scientific realism (SEP) remains popular, but there are a number of philosophical positions related to instrumentalism that undermine certainty.
For instance, theory-ladenness is the thesis that our concepts affect our perceptions, and therefore no perception is divorced from our pre-existing beliefs. An oversimplification of this would be to say that we see what believe or want to see. Observation sentences, therefore, are value-laden. Sellars famously outlined an attack on objectivity of perception with his Myth of the Given. McDowell takes it further in Mind and World and claims that perceptions and conceptions are fundamentally linked and rejects what he calls "bald naturalism" as another misapprehension.
In other words, what we see is a factor of what we look for and what we want to see to some extent. Thus, the idea that we each are objective video cameras that see only "the one true reality" is a folk-psychological myth. This turns the traditional notion of seeing-is-believing on its head by showing that believing-is-seeing. Under such a belief system, the idea there is an objective perception of the external physical reality is exposed as an abstraction that leaves out the biases and values of the viewer. Such a rejection of objectivity is strongly supported by embodied cognition (SEP) which suggests that we and our biology construct our perceptions from the lowest level of the visual system to the pinnacle of our belief system.
Richard Rorty, the self-proclaimed neo-pragmatist, extends this thesis even more fully arguing that not only is there no one right physical reality, that is a representation that irrefutable, that such reality is inextricably tied up in words and that words and truths themselves, in the spirit of LW's Sprachspiel, are community-oriented. This is what is called an anti-representationalist stance. And even if you reject this thesis, it is a very popular if not the dominant position of epistemologists that nothing can be shown through reason to be certain. Thus, a broad reading of analytical philosophy, at least, argues for fallibilism (IEP), the doctrine that there is no absolutely notion of certainty at all, a belief that methodological naturalism embraces with its emphasis on skeptical examination of data of all sorts, including perceptual data.

Excellent summary of contemporary philosophic thought challenging the realty of sense perception.  A quibble, though -- you led off with anti-realism, which I believe is still a minority view.  I think the consensus is more that uncertain realism: where "reality" is guessed at, never certain, is only approximated at one scale by our fallible senses, and plausibly could have multiple possibly incompatible "aspects" to it -- is the "most certain" realism we could possibly have.

@Dcleve When I get a chance, I'll edit to emphasize that realism along with physicals is the dominant paradigm. I meant to simply suggest that certainties and one-true-reality is a metaphysical position, not a fact.

"How can we be certain that the nature of things is as we perceive them, and are our cognitive tools (senses, logic, language)..."
Don't forget instrumentation.
Add it to the list.
We have tools for detection and analysis that outperform our limited human senses by orders of magnitude.
An MRI peers inside the human body, and gives insights to its workings.  X-rays.  We have radio-telescopes, and space-based super-infrared telescopes seeing billions and billions of years into the past.  Hadron colliders, and neutrino detectors and satellites orbiting Earth capturing records of gravitational anomaly patterns over time.
Instrumentation that tests and confirms and reconciles with our theories and expectations and predictions.
They are pretty much the answer to the question you are pondering, I would suggest.  The path to greater knowledge and understanding beyond our natural senses... way beyond.

On the contrary, you can be certain that many of our impressions about reality are just that- impressions. Light and shade, colour, sound, scent, warmth and texture are all qualities imagined by the mind. The sharp edges of a diamond are an illusion arising from the fact that you cannot see the microscopic structure. Etc etc.
